# subclassing a singleton

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

What is the recommended way, if any, to subclass a singleton?  For example,  I would like to make a subclass of `AVAudioSession` that adds a couple properties and makes the singleton its own `AVAudioSessionDelegate`.

Right now, I am overriding `sharedInstance` to allocate my own class, then call my own class' `init` method.  I am not sure if the other singleton methods need to be protected like a regular singleton, as the super class already is a singleton:

```
@interface PdAudioSession : AVAudioSession <AVAudioSessionDelegate>

@implementation PdAudioSession

+ (PdAudioSession *)sharedInstance {
    static PdAudioSession *myInstance = nil;
    @synchronized (self) {
        if (!myInstance) {
            myInstance = [[PdAudioSession alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return myInstance;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394033/whats-the-correct-method-to-subclass-a-singleton-class-in-objective-c. Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989344/objective-c-when-to-know-that-you-are-abusing-the-singleton-method-of-global-var

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than subclass the singleton, why not just create a new class that contains an `AVAudioSession` object. That way you can create it when you initialize your new class, you can add properties to this new class and also provide itself as a delegate.

Composition is the preferred design pattern in Cocoa over subclassing.

Comment: I started doing this, but then quit when I wanted to expose all the super methods (instead of reimplementing them all).  Still, this is probably the more sure fire way to go.

Comment: @reakinator: Implement this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/forwardingTargetForSelector:

Comment: The colon in @Peter Hosey's post should be part of the URL. Here's the modified URL: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/forwardingTargetForSelector:%20

Comment: @PeterHosey: that's nice trickery but you'd still end up with compiler warnings that aren't too nice to have in a public project.

Comment: @reakinator: What warnings would those be?